# Can the backlight of a screen go out, because a connection is loose?

Tags: display, macbook, connection, backlight

I have a macbook and it is 5 years old. The backlight of the monitor is temperamental.
I know it is the screen, because I can still see that the screen works when I look at it from an angle. So therefore it is not the logic boards:-)

Also the macbook works fine with an external monitor.

Now I was wondering could this be because of a connection of the monitor to the screen or is it time to get a new monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backlight can and regularly does go out due to a connector problem. In most screens/lids, there are two connectors: a display connector (usually LVDS, with a lot of pins), and a backlight connector (which usually has only two). There should be take-apart guides for your model of MacBook which will direct you on how to check the integrity and connection of the display cable on both ends: where it attaches to the screen, and where it attaches to the motherboard.

There is also often an inverter between the motherboard and the screen backlight proper, with two connections (in and out) on either end, which can become disconnected and cause the problem you are observing.

Comment: cool i'll look into it:-0

Comment: Don't know about macs but i've seen enough broken inverters and if someone asks to repair laptop without backlight then first thing to do is to check price of inverter board... and after that open it and look inside :)